# Complicated grouping and time difference

Tags: sql, t-sql

So I have a log table that is putting in data like:

```
LogId   SiteNumber  Unit        IDNumber    LogCode     EnteredDateTime            ChangeMode           HowEntered
-----   ----------  ----        --------    -------     ----------------           ----------           -----------
851     1           16 - 0      23502       BDISCHSET   2011-11-12 11:48:08.890    Discharging Soon     SERIES
866     1           16 - 0      NULL        BDISCHRED   2011-11-12 21:45:11.657    Discharged           SERIES  
113     2           2001 - 0    12384       BDISCHSET   2011-10-28 09:27:08.773    Discharging Soon     SERIES
125     2           2001 - 0    NULL        BDISCHRED   2011-10-28 10:38:08.060    Discharged           SERIES
119     2           2002 - 0    12394       BDISCHSET   2011-10-28 10:01:12.443    Discharging Soon     SERIES
139     2           2002 - 0    NULL        BDISCHRED   2011-10-28 14:01:11.120    Discharged           SERIES
776     2           2002 - 0    12331       BDISCHSET   2011-11-10 09:08:09.443    Discharging Soon     SERIES
783     2           2002 - 0    NULL        BDISCHRED   2011-11-10 11:08:08.537    Discharged           SERIES
```

What I need to do is group the records per person and calculate the amount of time it took to discharge.

For example:
Unit 2002 - 0 has two different people to group, it would be:

Person 12394 10/28/2011 from 10:01 to 14:01 = 4 hours to discharge

Person 12331 11/10/2011 from  9:08 to 11:08 = 2 hours to discharge

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do you know what the dischare time is for person 12394?

Comment: how can you tell that LogId 119 and 139 go together?

Comment: Yep. KM. No implied order in records- I agree with you and Stuart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others are pointing out in the comments, I don't think the design / architecture we're looking at is great.  If you can guarantee that rows will ALWAYS be sequential, i.e. for every set of two rows, the first row is a Patient with change mode of Discharging Soon and the 2nd row is the *same* patient with a change mode of Discharged, then this should work.

```
;WITH OrderedTable AS
(
    SELECT  Unit
            , IDNumber
            , EnteredDateTime
            , ROW_Number() OVER (Partition BY Unit ORDER BY Unit) RN 
    FROM    @t -- YOUR TABLE NAME GOES HERE
)
SELECT  t1.Unit
        , t1.IDNumber
        , t1.EnteredDateTime as TimeIn
        , t2.EnteredDateTime as TimeOut
        , DATEDIFF(hour, t1.EnteredDateTime, t2.EnteredDateTime ) TimeElapsedInHours
FROM    OrderedTable t1
JOIN    OrderedTable t2 ON t1.Unit = t2.Unit AND t2.RN = t1.RN + 1
WHERE   t1.RN % 2 <> 0
```

But I want to be clear - I don't know how safe this solution is based on your actual data.  However, it will give you the results you want, based on the sample data you provided.

Even if you can't use this exact approach because of your data model, I feel like there are a few things in it that you might could use to craft a solution.  These will make for interesting reading if nothing else.

- [DATEDIFF function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx)
- [Common Table Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx)
- [ROW_NUMBER function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

Here is the test I used...

```
declare @t TABLE
(
    LogId   int,
    SiteNumber  int,
    Unit        varchar(50),
    IDNumber    int ,
    LogCode   varchar(50),
    EnteredDateTime  datetime,          
    ChangeMode    varchar(50),       
    HowEntered varchar(50)
)

insert into @t values (851, 1, '16 - 0', 23502, 'BDISCHSET', '2011-11-12 11:48:08.890', 'Discharging Soon', 'SERIES')
insert into @t values (866, 1, '16 - 0 ', NULL, 'BDISCHRED', '2011-11-12 21:45:11.657', 'Discharged', 'SERIES')
insert into @t values (113, 2, '2001 - 0', 12384, 'BDISCHSET', '2011-10-28 09:27:08.773', 'Discharging Soon', 'SERIES')
insert into @t values (125, 2, '2001 - 0', NULL, 'BDISCHRED', '2011-10-28 10:38:08.060', 'Discharged', 'SERIES')
insert into @t values (119, 2, '2002 - 0', 12394, 'BDISCHSET', '2011-10-28 10:01:12.443', 'Discharging Soon', 'SERIES')
insert into @t values (139, 2, '2002 - 0', NULL, 'BDISCHRED', '2011-10-28 14:01:11.120', 'Discharged', 'SERIES')
insert into @t values (776, 2, '2002 - 0', 12331, 'BDISCHSET', '2011-11-10 09:08:09.443', 'Discharging Soon', 'SERIES')
insert into @t values (783, 2, '2002 - 0', NULL, 'BDISCHRED', '2011-11-10 11:08:08.537', 'Discharged', 'SERIES')

;WITH OrderedTable AS
(
    SELECT  Unit
            , IDNumber
            , EnteredDateTime
            , ROW_Number() OVER (Partition BY Unit ORDER BY Unit) RN 
    FROM    @t -- YOUR TABLE NAME GOES HERE
)
SELECT  t1.Unit
        , t1.IDNumber
        , t1.EnteredDateTime as TimeIn
        , t2.EnteredDateTime as TimeOut
        , DATEDIFF(hour, t1.EnteredDateTime, t2.EnteredDateTime ) TimeElapsedInHours
FROM    OrderedTable t1
JOIN    OrderedTable t2 ON t1.Unit = t2.Unit AND t2.RN = t1.RN + 1
WHERE   t1.RN % 2 <> 0
```

Comment: Thank you Jeremy and others. Yes I know this is ugly to work with which makes it tough, but it is what it is. I just know the discharge record goes with the person because it is in line with the date and time. Ugh. Thanks again, I will try this out.

Comment: All good, glad it worked.  I do think everyone raised valid points in their comments by the way, so definitely consider what they said.  Happy coding.  :)